# User.create not a function sequelize

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I just started using express js. I want to do a database insertion in to user table.
I used the sequelize model:generate to create a user model. This is it

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable('Users', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      email: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      password: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    });
  },
  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('Users');
  }
};
```

This is the model generated

```
'use strict';

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define('User', {
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    username: DataTypes.STRING,
    email: DataTypes.STRING,
    password: DataTypes.STRING
  });
  User.associate = function(models) {
    // associations can be defined here


  };  

  return User;
};
```

Then i have a controller where i have a register method.

```
const Validator = require('validatorjs');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const privateKey = require('../config.json').secretKey;
const saltRounds = require('../config.json').saltRounds;
const User = require('../models/user');

exports.register = async (req, res, next) => {
    rules = {
        username: 'required|string|max:255|alpha_num',
        email: 'required|email',
        password: 'required|string|max:255',
        name: 'required',
    }

    const validation = new Validator(req.body, rules);

    if(validation.passes()){
        let password = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, saltRounds);        
        User.create({
            username: req.body.username,
            password: password,
            name: req.body.name,
            email: req.body.email,            
        }).then(response => {
            return res.status(200).json(response);
        }).catch(err => {
            return res.status(500).json(err);
        });
    }else{
        return res.status(422).json(validation.errors);
    }

}
```

But I get an error saying User.create is not a function.
This is my file structure [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhgA5.png)

Please i need help with this. Appreciate

Comment: Why the strange mix of `await` and `then(...)`? If you're using `async` functions, use `await`! Likewise, if your first `if (user === null)` succeeds then it will `return` meaning there's no need for the `else`, that's implicit, so you can de-indent the rest by promoting it to regular code below the `if { ... }`

Comment: You've exported a function which you're requiring with `const User = require('../models/user');`. But it looks like this function needs to be called with 2 params to return the actual `User` model which you can then call `.create` and `.findOne` etc on. I recommend posting a [mcve]--this question could be improved by cutting out a lot of the noise that basically seems unrelated to the problem you're asking about. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you generate your models with sequelize CLI `sequelize-cli model:generate --name User` you should import them from the `index.js` file in the `models` folder

```
const db = require('../models');
db.User.create({})
```